# Android Annotations Custom View

Tags: java, android, annotations, android-annotations

I am trying to implement Android Annotations to my View. But I cant figure out how to do it correctly. My Problem at the moment is that the fields in the View are always NULL.

I think I have a bit of an understanding problem how to use Android Annotations with Views and Adapters. Can someone give me a hint how I would do this correctly?

In my fragment I use the following adapter:

**ItemAdapter**

```
@EBean
public class ItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

public ItemAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    GalleryListView view;
    if (convertView == null) {
        view = GalleryListView_.build(context);
    } else {
        view = (GalleryListView) convertView;
    }

    imageUrls = getDocumentListAll();
    DDocuments doc = documentProxy.getElementByDocument(imageUrls.get(position));
    view.init(imageUrls.get(position), Uri.fromFile(new File(doc.getPath())));

    // before I used annotations I did set my Image using this. But now I dont really know how to use this line
    // ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(Uri.fromFile(new File(doc.getPath())).toString(), holder.image, options, animateFirstListener);
}
}
```

**GalleryListView**

```
@EViewGroup(R.layout.gallery_list)
public class GalleryListView extends LinearLayout {
    @ViewById
    ImageView   image;

    @ViewById
    TextView    text;

    public void init(String imageText, Uri imageUri) {
        text.setText(imageText);
        image.setImageURI(imageUri);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the Views have not been injected when you're making your call to init.  So, a solution should be to not set the view's text directly; rather, you want to set a variable that you know will be read into the Views after they have been injected.

One way to do this is to make use of [@AfterViews](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Injecting-Views). A method with the @AfterViews annotation will be called after View injection has taken place.

Off the top of my head it would look like this:

```
@EViewGroup(R.layout.gallery_list)
public class GalleryListView extends LinearLayout {
    String mText;
    Uri mUri;

    @ViewById
    ImageView   image;

    @ViewById
    TextView    text;

    public void init(String imageText, Uri imageUri) {
        mText = imageText;
        mUri = imageUri;
    }

    @AfterViews
    void afterViews() {
        text.setText(mText);
        image.setImageURI(mUri);
    }
}
```

This might not be the best solution, but it should get the job done.  I suggest keeping the [Android Annotation Cookbook](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Cookbook) handy; there are other similar annotations that will come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you getting context from?

Try replacing

```
    view = GalleryListView_.build(context);
```

with

```
    view = new GalleryListView_(context);
```

In any case, for such a small view I don't see the profit of using Android Annotations, maybe if you had multiple resources I would understand, but for such little code, I recommend you to implement te constructor and inflate the resources yourself there.

Comment: unfortunately it didnt work. I get the context from my *GalleryFragment*: `final ItemAdapter documentAdapter = new ItemAdapter(getActivity());
listView.setAdapter(documentAdapter);`

this is only a very small part of my project. I use (I want to, since I'm not done refactoring) android annotations for the whole project. Without annotations I got it running again, so maybe I'll leave it as it is for the moment. Thanks for your tipp!